# Balls and bins confusion, why can't we just divide by r!

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, balls-in-bins

Explain the mistake in the following “counting argument”: Suppose we want to count the number of ways that r indistinguishable balls can be placed in n distinct bins, under the assumption that each bin can take more than one ball and that the order of the balls inside the bin does not count. Assume first that the balls are distinct. Then there are $n^r$ ways to place them into the bins under the same assumptions. Divide this number by $r!$ to make up for the fact that the balls are indistinguishable to get $n^r/ r! $.

Answer (score 2):

What if all the balls are in one bin? Which $r!$ different configurations are you dividing out then?

Comment: 2 bins, 5 balls, your formula gives $\frac{32}{120}$ options to dispatch the balls. Bad luck, this number is not an integer.

Comment: If we assume that the correct answer to the problem stated is (n+r-1)!/(n-1)!r! than we are also dividing by r!. I was thinking that the reason why we use (n+r-1)!(n-1)! is that upon placing a ball we add one more possibility for placing another one. Then if we divide by number of ways of placing the same flags in different order (r!)). While dividing by n^r by r! would account for the repetitions, it would not account for the fact that when the balls are indistinguishable and the order does not matter (but it matters in n^r).